# Bending a rectangle while keeping its rounded corners and width on Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Hello everyone I am trying to add a bent rectangle parallel to the rhombus while keeping the width and rounded corners of the rectangle. So far I only create a rectangle and used the "Archer Point Tool" to bend it and align it with the rhombus. So far I have:

[image]

I am trying to achieve something like the below design:

[image]

How can I do this using illustrator I tried adding shapes next to what I have now but they do not align well even after smoothing.

Sorry, I am a beginner so I do not know how to use illustrator that well.

Comment: Use offset, then cut.

Comment: It is quite interesting to see how people approach this differently

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Duplicate the diamond four times
- Use **Pathfinder** (or Shapebuilder) to define the second shape
- Add rounding

[image]

Cut the bottom shape narrower if you need.

I'm using AstuteGraphics Dynamic Corners here, but it can be done with CC versions of Illustrator with the corner widget or even the Round Corners Effect within Illustrator.

Answer (score 8):

1. Create your shape
2. Object> Path> Offset Path (set to desired value and make black stroke with no fill)
3. Draw horizontal line (with black stroke and no fill)
4. Select Line and Offset shape
5. Pathfinder> Divide
6. Delete unwanted sections of Offset path
7. Increase Stroke weight as desired
8. Object> Path> Outline Stroke
9. Select both shapes and use corner widgets for rounding

[image]